# Big Oh of values of Riemann zeta function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

There is a equality in a proof in Apostol's Analytic Number Theory as follows:
$O(x^{\alpha} \zeta(\alpha)) = O(x^{\alpha})$ for arbitrary real number $\alpha \ge 0$.

How do we say that? Does anything changes when $\alpha \in [0,1]$?

Comment: It is not correct. Check out $\zeta(1)$ for $\alpha=1$, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function). What section/chapter is this in Apostol?

Comment: It is in Chapter 3, Theorem 3.5.

Comment: My bad, $\alpha$ is any positive number except $1$. What happens now?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is - as far as the implied limit there is concerned - for fixed $\alpha$ as $x$ varies, $\zeta(\alpha)$ is just a number. $O(cf(x))=O(f(x))$ for any constant $c$ and function $f$.

As noted in the comments, $\alpha=1$ is an exception; there, $O(x^{\alpha}\zeta(\alpha))$ becomes $O(\infty)$, which is vacuously true for any function of $x$.

In practice, the places you'll actually want to use this always come from values of $\alpha$ for which the series for $\zeta$ converges - namely, $\alpha>1$. However, it's still true for $\alpha<1$, using the definitionof $\zeta$ by analytic continuation.

Comment: OK, $\alpha=1$ is special. $O(\infty)$ is a rather meaningless proposition.